# Update related model field through a view (Django REST)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class Question(models.Model):
   ...
   posted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   # following fields are for sorting by popularity
   popular_param = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

class Answer(models.Model):
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ...
   posted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**What I want to achieve:**
Whenever an *Answer* is created, *popular_param* of the *Question* model should be incremented by 10.

I have tried the following, by overriding *perform_create* in the viewset.

```
class PostAnswerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    this is where you post answers
    """
    queryset = Answer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostAnswerSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        answer = self.get_object()
        answer.question.popular_param = F('popular_param') + 10
        answer.question.save()
        serializer.save()
```

OR

```
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        Answer.question.popular_param = F('popular_param') + 10
        Answer.question.save()
        serializer.save()
```

I seem to be missing some syntax but can't figure out what. None of the other questions on SO have helped so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
class PostAnswerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    this is where you post answers
    """
    queryset = Answer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostAnswerSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        answer = serializer.save()
        answer.question.popular_param = F('popular_param') + 10
        answer.question.save()
```

Because the `Answer` object will be created when called `serializer.save()`. Before that, I don't think we can `get_object()`.

Comment: I got the following error- AttributeError : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'question'

Comment: Sorry for my mistake :D